# Efficient schedule organizer

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, scheduler

So I'm working on a practice project right now and I'm stuck.

The program is supposed to take a list of events in a day (That have a start time, end time and duration) and then find the most efficient schedule (meaning the time spent in a event is maximised)

My attempt currently has a method that takes the list and then orders it from earliest start time to latest. If the start time of the event is the same as another event then it will compare duration for the longer event and place that one earlier.

Then, it should take that list and basically keep plugging them into a arraylist until it overlaps. If it overlaps it should branch out into 2 separate schedules (1 with one of the events that overlapped and 1 with the other) then it will continue plugging in the events until there are no more events in the list.

After that it will take all the schedules and compare the total duration in a event and find the greatest total duration and print that schedule out.

**The problem-**
When I plug the schedules into a schedules arraylist, they keep updating and I end up having an arraylist of of all the same schedules which defeat the purpose of having this arraylist. I read that it is due to the nature of the arraylist and how objects are read. **So now I'm wondering how do I have a list that I can keep plugging in schedules into and then using that list to compare all the durations?**

Code:

```
    ArrayList<Event> list1 = new ArrayList<Event>(); // Unorganized list of events
    ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> schedules = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(); // will hold List of schedules

    list1 = organizeEventList(list); 
    newList.add(0); //initialize newList with first item of list1
    schedules.add(newList);

    for (int schedulePos = 0; schedulePos < schedules.size(); schedulePos++ ){
        newList = schedules.get(schedulePos);

        for (int x = newList.get(newList.size()-1); x < list1.size()-1; x++){

            int listPos = newList.get(newList.size()-1); // get the list position of the last item of newList
            int key = listPos +1;

            boolean overlap = checkForOverlap(list1.get(listPos).getStartTime(), list1.get(listPos).getEndTime(), list1.get(key).getStartTime(), list1.get(key).getEndTime()); 

            //overlap is true. Duplicate the list and have 1 schedule with event of key and 1 with event of x
            if (overlap == true){
                schedules.add(newList); 
                newList.remove(newList.size()-1);
                newList.add(key);
                schedules.add(schedules.size(), newList);
            }

            else {
                newList.add(key);
                schedules.set((schedules.size()-1), newList);
            }

            newList = schedules.get(schedulePos);
            key++;
        }

    }

    /*
     * Goal: take durations of all schedules in the schedules list and find the most efficient one
     * How? Starting with the schedule in the first spot. Use all their integers to find their durations from list1 and add them to a integer variable. 
     * Store the finished duration to durations arraylist
     * For loop again to find the longest duration from the duration arraylist
     * Take that arraylist from schedules and set newList to that schedule and print it out
     */
    ArrayList<Integer> durations = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int duration = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < schedules.size(); x++){

        for (int x1 = 0; x1 < schedules.get(x1).size()-1; x1++){
            duration += list1.get(schedules.get(x).get(x1)).getDuration();
        }

        durations.add(duration);

    }

    int schedulesPos = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < durations.size(); x++){
        int longestDuration = 0;
        if (durations.get(x) > longestDuration){
            longestDuration = durations.get(x);
            schedulesPos = x;
        }

        else if (durations.get(x) == longestDuration){
            System.out.println("Schedule with the same time efficiency was found." );
        }

    }
    ArrayList<Event> finishedList = new ArrayList<Event>();

    for (int x = 0; x < schedules.get(schedulesPos).size(); x++){
        finishedList.add(list1.get(schedules.get(schedulesPos).get(x)));
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < finishedList.size(); i++){
        System.out.printf("[%s] %s - %s \n", finishedList.get(i).getTitle(), convertIntToTime(finishedList.get(i).getStartTime()), convertIntToTime(finishedList.get(i).getEndTime()));
    }

}
```

I'm sorry if this seems messy, I'm still fairly new to programming.

Comment: You may consider using a Queue for this. It is not easy to read your code. Too many list iterations and long methods. Keep your methods short and use the enhanced for loop.

Comment: You use the same `newList`. All the references are to the same object, and you just remove and delete from the same list. You should create a *copy* of the list if you want to have duplicate lists.

Comment: Your problem is called [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) and is NP-complete, so there is no efficient solution but maybe you study this problem a little bit to write a correct solution

Comment: More precisely, there is no algorithm that is *guaranteed* to find the optimal solution in `O(N^C)` time for some constant C.  There are heuristic algorithms that will find passable to good solutions all of the time, and an algorithm may hit on the optimal solution for some problems.

Comment: Also this means that if N is small enough, it is computationally feasible to find the optimal solution for problems of size N.  In other words, NP complete doesn't mean "give up".

Comment: @Obenland: The knapsack problem is a special case of this problem: to turn an instance of the knapsack problem into an instance of this problem, make an event for each item, and assign the start and end times of each event to 0 and the knapsack capacity, respectively.  An algorithm to solve this scheduling problem also needs to be able to handle the more general case where events have different start or end times.